Does “mischief” in 5:32 mean disobeying allah?
I came across a few claims about surah 5:52:

That is why We ordained for the Children of Israel that whoever takes
a life—unless as a punishment for murder or mischief in the land—it
will be as if they killed all of humanity; and whoever saves a life,
it will be as if they saved all of humanity.1 ˹Although˺ Our
messengers already came to them with clear proofs, many of them still
transgressed afterwards through the land.

What ive heard these people claim is that “mischief” in this case, relates to disobeying allah, which, to them, means that muslims should kill all non muslims
But didnt muslims go along fine with  non muslims(that didnt attack/oppress them) in the past? With them even being allowed to live among them?
Is this really what it means? I cant imagine it being taken in the way these people frame it as? Can someone help me with this?

Mischief here includes everything which makes shedding of blood lawful in Islamic law (Tafsir al-Razi, Tafsir al-Baghawy). This include e.g. disbelief, adultery, banditry, apostasy etc.
It includes disbelief as it is permitted to shed the blood of a disbeliever by default. There are however exceptions, not all disbelievers must be killed, rather those disbelievers can be killed who are adult male harbi, or apostates or those from whom jizyah can not be accepted. See Does every non-Muslim need to accept Islam or die? Also by itself this verse does not imply that they should be killed, rather it makes it permissible.
The evidence that the blood of a disbeliever is lawful by default is the Quran where it tells us to kill the polytheists, the hadith where it is said that it is accepting Islam that makes blood sacred, the athar that the blood of a disbeliever is like the blood of a dog and consensus etc.

اتفق الفقهاء على أن دم الكافر الحربي - وهو غير الذمي والمعاهد والمؤمن - مهدر، فإن قتله مسلم فلا تبعة عليه إذا كان مقاتلا، أما إذا كان الكافر الحربي غير مقاتل كالنساء والصبيان والعجزة والرهبان وغيرهم ممن ليسوا أهلا للقتال أو لتدبيرها فلا يجوز قتله
The jurists are agreed that the blood of a Kafir Harbi -and he is one who is other than a dhimmi, mu‘aahid or one who has asylum- is permissible, hence if he is one who can fight and a Muslim kills him then nothing is due on the killer, however if the Harbi is not one who can fight, such as a child, woman, old person or monk etc. who is not eligible to fight then their killing is not permissible
— Mawsoo‘ah al-Fiqhiyyah


بأن الله تبارك وتعالى حرم دم المؤمن وماله إلا بواحدة ألزمه إياها، وأباح دم الكافر وماله إلا بأن يؤدي الجزية أو يستأمن إلى مدة
Allah has made the blood and property of a Muslim sacred, except when he himself makes a violation which renders it lawful. And Allah has made the blood and property of a disbeliever lawful except when he pays Jizya or is given asylum for a limited period of time
— Kitab al-Umm 

